# How to Show a Table data with Alphabetical Table in Php mySql?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have a dictionary database with 950 rows of data. I would like to show the words list in alphabetical order in alphabetical table wise.

For an example table a shows first (5) words of data's starts from A:

```
A
-------------
Abacus
Abelian group
Abscissa
Absolute Value
Abstract Number

B
---------------
Bar Graph
Base
Base Depth of the Triangular Prism
Base of the Triangular Prism
Basic arithmetic operations

.
.
.

Z
---------------
Z-Intercept
Zero
Zero Divisors
Zero Element
Zone
```

every 5 data's fetch table should stop the current letter and jump to next letter.

I don't know how to do this.

My Table structure is

```
-------------------------
Name    |   Type
-------------------------
Id  |   int(3)
Word    |   varchar(45)
-------------------------
```

Comment: use `ORDER BY` clause. like
**SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `Word`**

Comment: k. but how to switch a first letter(B) after getting 5 words from alphabet letter A. i want a table for A to Z with 5 words.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract first letter with [left](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

```
select left(word, 1) from table;
```

function and use huge union all query. details is described with examples in [here](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/).

Answer (score 0):

I tried below query which has limit for now of 3.

In short what we have to do is - **group by sorted words and limit to n**

1. Created table as `word_table`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `offers`.`word_table` ( `Id` INT(3) NOT NULL , `Word`
> VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
> ```

2. Inserted your record in table

> ```
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('1', 'Abacus'); 
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('2', 'Abelian group');
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('3', 'Abscissa'); 
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('4', 'Absolute Value');
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('5', 'Abstract Number');
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('6', 'Bar Graph'); 
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('7', 'Base');
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('8', 'Base Depth of the Triangular Prism');
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('9', 'Base of the Triangular Prism');
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('10', 'Basic arithmetic operations');
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('11', 'Z-Intercept');
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('12', 'Zero');
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('13', 'Zero Divisors');
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('14', 'Zero Element');
>
> INSERT INTO `word_table` (`Id`, `Word`) VALUES ('15', 'Zone');
> ```

**Query** written for required output

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @category != substring(t.Word,1,1) THEN @rownum := 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 
               END AS rank,
               @category := substring(t.Word,1,1) AS var_category
          FROM word_table t
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @category := '') r
      ORDER BY t.Word) x
 WHERE x.rank <= 3  
ORDER BY `x`.`var_category`  ASC
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Hope this helps you!!!

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. It will be helpful to other users

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single query to get the result of both the distinct first character and all the records with that letter as starting letter by using this

```
SELECT lower(left(filed_name,1)) as letter, group_concat(filed_name) as all_records FROM `table_name`  where lower(left(filed_name,1)) in(SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(filed_name, 1) FROM table_name order by filed_name) group by lower(left(filed_name,1)) ORDER BY filed_name  ASC
```